# Xoml only Workflow parameters

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation

Is is possible to pass parameters to an XOML only workflow?

I'm creating the workflow using XmlReader.

Now is it possible to have parameters on an xoml only workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can pass Parameters to a Xoml based workflow.  You would use the `CreateWorkflow` overload that takes also the rulesReader but pass null for that parameter:-

```
XmlReader xoml = GetXoml();
Dictionary params = CreateMyParams();

WorkflowInstance instance = workflowRuntime.CreateWorkflow(xoml, null, params);
```

Comment: Typically the top-level Activity is custom activity derived from the `SequentialWorkflowActivity`  property names on this Activity would match the Key names in the params dictionary.

Comment: thanks, that's what I did. Created a base class with properties and make the xoml root as the base class